# Cannot link filesystem library in SDK

Tags: yocto

I am trying to use the filesystem library from C++17 while compiling with SDK.
I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494654).

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    const std::string path = "/tmp/";
    for (const auto & entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}
```

I have a problem when linking the library (only while compiling with SDK, it works on Ubuntu.)
Should I enable c++17 for SDK somehow?
Or should I add stdc++fs library to the SDK?

Comment: what exactly do you do and what error do you get?

Comment: I try to compile the code above using SDK. I see I am missing stdc++fs. How can I add this lib to the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " libstdc++-staticdev"
```